# Lifetimes for method returning iterator of structs with same lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Assume the following contrived example:

```
struct Board {
    squares: Vec<i32>,
}

struct Point<'a> {
    board: &'a Board,
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl<'a> Point<'a> {
    pub fn neighbors(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Point<'a>> {
        [(0, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0)]
            .iter().map(|(dx, dy)| Point {
                board: self.board,
                x: self.x + dx,
                y: self.y + dy,
            })
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile because from what I understand the lifetime of the points created in the lambda isn't correct:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:14:25
   |
14 |               .iter().map(|(dx, dy)| Point {
   |  _________________________^
15 | |                 board: self.board,
16 | |                 x: self.x + dx,
17 | |                 y: self.y + dy,
18 | |             })
   | |_____________^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 12:5...
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 | /     pub fn neighbors(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Point<'a>> {
13 | |         [(0, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0)]
14 | |             .iter().map(|(dx, dy)| Point {
15 | |                 board: self.board,
...  |
18 | |             })
19 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected &&Point<'_>
              found &&Point<'a>
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 11:1...
  --> src/main.rs:11:1
   |
11 | impl<'a> Point<'a> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that return value is valid for the call
  --> src/main.rs:12:32
   |
12 |     pub fn neighbors(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Point<'a>> {
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm a bit lost as to why this is the case though, because it seems like the lifetimes here make sense. A `Point`'s lifetime is caused by the lifetime of the reference to the `Board`. Thus, a `Point<'a>` has a reference to a board with lifetime `'a` so it should be able to create more `Point<'a>`s because their board references will have the same lifetime (`'a`).

But, if I remove the lambda, it works:

```
impl<'a> Point<'a> {
    pub fn neighbors(&self) -> [Point<'a>; 4] {
        [
            Point { board: self.board, x: self.x    , y: self.y - 1},
            Point { board: self.board, x: self.x - 1, y: self.y    },
            Point { board: self.board, x: self.x + 1, y: self.y    },
            Point { board: self.board, x: self.x    , y: self.y + 1},
        ]
    }
}
```

So, I suspect the problem lies in the fact that the lambda may be run after the lifetime `'a` ends. But, does this mean that I can't lazily produce these points?

tl;dr How do I make the borrow checker happy with a method that lazily creates new structs whose lifetimes are tied to the struct creating them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have this kind of issue in a method, a good thing to do is to add an explicit lifetime to `&self`:

```
pub fn neighbors(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Point<'a>> {
    [(0, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0)]
        .iter().map(|(dx, dy)| Point {
            board: self.board,
            x: self.x + dx,
            y: self.y + dy,
        })
}
```

The error is now better

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `self`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:14:30
   |
14 |             .iter().map(|(dx, dy)| Point {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `self`
15 |                 board: self.board,
   |                        ---- `self` is borrowed here
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `self` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
14 |             .iter().map(move |(dx, dy)| Point {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You then just need to add the `move` keyword as advised by the compiler, to say to it that you will not use `&'a self` again.

Note that the lifetime of `self` has not to be the same as the lifetime of `Point`. This is better to use this signature:

```
fn neighbors<'b>(&'b self) -> impl 'b + Iterator<Item = Point<'a>>
```

Comment: Indeed! It's a shame that the error message for both isn't the same (because the one you provoked is definitely a lot more explicit that "other referenced variables" could be the problem). Thanks so much! (Also as a note, I was able to get this working with an array by only adding the `move` and the lifetime to `self` in 1.26; I'm unsure if you were implying that I needed to keep the vector)

Comment: @BaileyParker I was implying that; I cannot explain why this compiles. My answer is still incomplete, then.

Comment: @BaileyParker I removed the stuff about the array

Comment: @BaileyParker FYI, I asked a question about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345139/do-this-code-returns-a-reference-to-a-local-variable

Answer (score 3):

Both the existing answers ([Shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50351826/3650362), [Boiethios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50343342/3650362)) allow the `Point`s returned by the iterator to outlive the iterator itself. However, it should be possible to build an iterator that even outlives the original `Point` it was created from, by moving the contents of the `Point` into it. This version retains the original function signature:

```
fn neighbors(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Point<'a>> {
    let Point { board, x, y } = *self;
    [(0, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0)]
        .iter().map(move |(dx, dy)| Point {
            board: board,
            x: x + dx,
            y: y + dy,
        })
}
```

Copying the contents of `*self` into local variables which are moved into the closure makes it so the closure -- and therefore the returned iterator -- no longer contains any references to `self`.

Here's something you can do with this version that can't be done otherwise ([playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a4dbc41c7cd6c964597999318f4a6cf3&version=stable&mode=debug)):

```
let mut p = Point {
    board: &b,
    x: 10,
    y: 12,
};
for n in p.neighbors() {
    p = n;
}
```

One potential caveat is that if `Point` contains very large or non-`Copy` data that can't or shouldn't be moved into the closure, this won't work. In that case you should use the other solution:

```
fn neighbors<'b>(&'b self) -> impl 'b + Iterator<Item = Point<'a>>
```

Comment: @Boiethios There are cases where this won't work and one might have to fall back to a more restrictive signature. I've added a disclaimer

Comment: This is a good point. I hadn't much considered usage context. For my particular case, it may make more sense to not make point `Copy`, but if it was it looks like you're correct in that I should store the fields on `self` that I need in locals. Bioethios had the root cause right, but this is a good point. Wish I could give the check to both :)

Answer (score 2):

I would assign a lifetime to `self` that is distinct from the lifetime of the `Board`:

```
impl<'b> Point<'b> {
    fn neighbors<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Point<'b>> + 'a {
        [(0, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0)]
            .iter().map(move |(dx, dy)| Point {
                board: self.board,
                x: self.x + dx,
                y: self.y + dy,
            })
    }
}
```

This also requires marking the closure as `move` to move the `&Self` value into the closure so that the closure can still access `board`, `x` and `y` when it is advanced. Since immutable references can be copied, this won't prevent the caller from doing anything.

Without the separate lifetimes, the lifetimes of the `Point`s returned from the iterator are artificially limited to the lifetime of the `Point` that generated them. As an example, this code fails when the lifetimes are unified, but works when they are distinct:

```
fn example<'b>(board: &'b Board) {
    let _a = {
        let inner = Point { board, x: 0, y: 0 };
        let mut n = inner.neighbors();
        n.next().unwrap()
    };
}
```

See also:

- [When is it useful to define multiple lifetimes in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29861388/155423)

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered this. Just to be sure, the reason why your example fails is because board has lifetime `'b` but `inner`'s lifetime is tied to the scope assigned to `_a` (which are distinct)?

Comment: @BaileyParker it will fail because the unified lifetimes (`fn neighbors(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Point<'a>>`) means that the returned `Point`s might contain a reference to `self` / the origin `Point`.