# How to return a Rust closure that borrows state to use later?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I have a fairly simple bit of code. I have a feeling I need to use a lifetime to accomplish this but I'm stumped right now.

`parse_string` is a function that accepts a reference to a string, and returns a closure to be used later, here's the code:

```
fn main() {
    let parse_this = parse_string(&String::from("Hello!"));
    println!("{}", parse_this("goodbye!"));
}

fn parse_string(string: &String) -> impl Fn(&str) -> &String {
    return |targetString| {
        // pretend there is parsing logic
        println!("{}", targetString);
        return string;
    };
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime
  --> src/main.rs:7:12
   |
6  |   fn parse_string(string: &String) -> impl Fn(&str) -> &String {
   |                                       ------------------------ this return type evaluates to the `'static` lifetime...
7  |       return |targetString| {
   |  ____________^
8  | |         // pretend there is parsing logic
9  | |         println!("{}", targetString);
10 | |         return string;
11 | |     };
   | |_____^ ...but this borrow...
   |
note: ...can't outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 6:1
  --> src/main.rs:6:1
   |
6  | / fn parse_string(string: &String) -> impl Fn(&str) -> &String {
7  | |     return |targetString| {
8  | |         // pretend there is parsing logic
9  | |         println!("{}", targetString);
10 | |         return string;
11 | |     };
12 | | }
   | |_^
help: you can add a constraint to the return type to make it last less than `'static` and match the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 6:1
   |
6  | fn parse_string(string: &String) -> impl Fn(&str) -> &String + '_ {
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0312]: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
  --> src/main.rs:10:16
   |
10 |         return string;
   |                ^^^^^^
   |
note: ...the reference is valid for the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 7:12...
  --> src/main.rs:7:12
   |
7  |       return |targetString| {
   |  ____________^
8  | |         // pretend there is parsing logic
9  | |         println!("{}", targetString);
10 | |         return string;
11 | |     };
   | |_____^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 6:1
  --> src/main.rs:6:1
   |
6  | / fn parse_string(string: &String) -> impl Fn(&str) -> &String {
7  | |     return |targetString| {
8  | |         // pretend there is parsing logic
9  | |         println!("{}", targetString);
10 | |         return string;
11 | |     };
12 | | }
   | |_^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of compounding issues:

1. You need an explicit lifetime to connect the lifetime of the `string` argument to the lifetime of the return value of the returned closure. Right now, [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html?highlight=elision#lifetime-elision) causes it to be inferred  the same as the *argument* to the closure.
2. You cannot return a reference to the temporary through the function. It needs to be a distinct variable.
3. You have to move `string` into the closure to prevent taking another reference to it, which wouldn't live long enough.

Additionally...

1. `targetString` should be `target_string` to follow Rust idioms.
2. `return` should not be used at the end of a block to follow Rust idioms.
3. `&str` is generally preferred to `&String`

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("Hello!");
    let parse_this = parse_string(&s);
    println!("{}", parse_this("goodbye!"));
}

fn parse_string<'a>(string: &'a String) -> impl Fn(&str) -> &'a String {
    return move |target_string| {
        // pretend there is parsing logic
        println!("{}", target_string);
        string
    };
}
```

See also:

- [Lifetimes for method returning iterator of structs with same lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50343130/155423)
- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)
- [Getting "temporary value dropped while borrowed" when trying to update an Option<&str> in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54488127/155423)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an explicit lifetime annotation to `parse_string` so that the compiler can tell which lifetimes are the same and which may be different.

`Fn(&str) -> &String` would be the type for a function that returns a `&String` of the same lifetime as the `&str` passed in; i.e., `for<'b> Fn(&'b str) -> &'b String`. You need to say that the `&String` returned has the same lifetime as the `&String` passed in to `parse_string`:

```
fn parse_string<'a>(string: &'a String) -> impl Fn(&str) -> &'a String {
```

Note that `Fn(&str)` doesn't have a lifetime annotation; this is because the lifetime of the `&str` passed into the *closure* is unrelated to the lifetime of the `&String` passed into `parse_string`.

In order to make `parse_string` compile, you need to make one more change. Closures try to borrow their environment if the compiler thinks it doesn't need to be moved. Your closure, which borrows `string`, can't be returned from the function where `string` is a local variable. To fix this, you `move` the captured variable into the closure:

```
    move |target_string| {
        // pretend there is parsing logic
        println!("{}", target_string);
        string
    }
```

It's idiomatic in Rust to omit the `return` in the last expression in a function.

Also note that `&String` is an unusual type because it offers no expressivity that `&str` does not provide. It is almost always a mistake to have `&String` in non-generic code. See [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o) for more information.

Putting it all together, here's how I'd write `parse_string`:

```
fn parse_string<'a>(string: &'a str) -> impl Fn(&str) -> &'a str {
    move |target_string| {
        // pretend there is parsing logic
        println!("{}", target_string);
        string
    }
}
```

Your `main` also needs a small tweak: `&String::from("Hello!")` takes a reference to a temporary `String` that will be dropped immediately at the end of the line, invalidating the reference. This is easily fixed by storing the `String` in a variable so it will not be dropped until the end of the scope:

```
fn main() {
    let hello = String::from("Hello!");
    let parse_this = parse_string(&hello);
    println!("{}", parse_this("goodbye!"));
}
```

Comment: I'm actually not sure why `string` is reborrowed here instead of moved. Guess the compiler just isn't quite clever enough