# Does Rust narrow lifetimes to satisfy constraints defined on them?

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

Please consider this example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=93c480dd7d5da133a3d98463c0fd3413)):

```rust
struct Container<'short, 'long: 'short, T: 'long> {
    short_prop: &'short u8,
    long_prop: &'long T,
}

fn main() {
    let value = 9;
    let long = &value;

    {
        let short = &value;
        let res = Container {
            short_prop: long,
            long_prop: short, // why is this not an error?
        };

        println!("{} {}", res.short_prop, res.long_prop);
    }
}
```

In `Container` I specify `'long: 'short` which I'm *assuming* means that `'long` should live at least as long as `'short`. In `main`, the variable `long` should live longer than `short` because it has a bigger scope.

So `Container` expects whatever goes into `long_prop` to live at least as long as whatever goes into `short_prop`. Yet the compiler is perfectly happy with me passing the longer-lived `long` into `short_prop` and the shorter-lived `short` into `long_prop`.

Is this because at the instantiation of `Container` the compiler narrows the lifetime of `long` to be equal to the lifetime of `short` thus satisfying the `'long: 'short` constraint (since equality of lifetimes is fine)? Or is there another reason?

Comment: I not seen a case in recent history where `'foo: 'bar` has been useful. Either it was redundant or **wrong** (when unsafe code was involved).

Comment: See also [When is it useful to define multiple lifetimes in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29861388/155423); [Why would you ever use the same lifetimes for references in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44709632/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster I only saw `'foo: 'bar` here: https://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-ownership-the-hard-way/ (ctrl-f for "DecodeResult") But I don't really understand that example. If anything, I'd expect the lifetime relationship to be `'decoded: 'buf` instead of `'buf: 'decoded` because the pointed (`'buf`) must live longer than the pointer (`'decoded`). But then again, that's only if we need this magic at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this because at the instantiation of `Container` the compiler narrows the lifetime of `'long` to be equal to the lifetime of `'short` thus satisfying the `'long: 'short` constraint (since equality of lifetimes is fine)?

Yes.

> Or is there another reason?

Nope.

Here's an example with a simpler `Container` struct which only holds 1 reference at a time. The reason it can hold both `long` and `short` references is because longer lifetimes are subtypes of shorter ones, but the overall lifetime of the `container` variable is narrowed to the minimum overlap of both of these lifetimes, which means `container` goes out of scope the same time as `short` does:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Container<'a> {
    some_ref: &'a str
}

fn main() {
    let long = String::from("long");
    let long_ref = &long;
    
    let mut container = Container {
        some_ref: long_ref,
    };
    
    dbg!(&container);

    {
        let short = String::from("short");
        let short_ref = &short;

        container.some_ref = short_ref;

        dbg!(&container);
    } // both short & container go out of scope here
    
    dbg!(&container); // error, container dropped in block above, has same lifetime as short
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7205dd8d58fa9452da29ae60fb3f82f0)